# How can i write a short error message in console and completely in file

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I have two log handler, console and file :

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()

c_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
f_handler = logging.FileHandler('errors.log')

logger.addHandler(c_handler)
logger.addHandler(f_handler)
```

when i face an exception i want to write a short message in console and completely in file. something like this:

```
a = 5
b = 0

try:
  c = a / b
except Exception as e:
  logger.error("Exception occurred", exc_info=True)
```

what i want in console:

```
log - ERROR - Exception occurred (ZeroDivisionError: division by zero)
```

and in file :

```
log - ERROR - Exception occurred
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "index.py", line 20, in <module>
c = a / b
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

how can i achieve that. thanks

Comment: @Vinay Sajip ...